# Como formatar o nome de um item numa listbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou com um projeto em que tenho que enviar arquivos pela rede para um servidor.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando clico no botão "adicionar" abre uma caixa para a pessoa selecionar os arquivos que quer enviar e adiciona numa lista que armazena objetos do tipo "Arquivo".

Até ai tudo bem, mas o nome está aparecendo que nem na imagem. Como que eu faço para que apareça o nome do arquivo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma das formas de fazer isso é redefenindo o método `ToString` da classe.

```
public override string ToString() {
    return "Meu texto aqui";
}
```

Outra hipótese é defenir um valor para [`DisplayMember`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember(v=vs.110).aspx). Esta propriedade recebe o nome duma propriedade defenida na classe para apresentar como texto.

```
ListBox1.DisplayMember = "MeuCampoComTexto";
```

Comment: Obrigado cara! O seu foi o mais simples e o que funcionou foi esse "Listbox1.Displaymember" que deu certo. Eu coloquei o atributo "nome" nele e apareceu o nome do arquivo. Obrigado aos outros também porque implementei aqui e ficou mais bonito.

Answer (score 5):

Use essa função para retornar o nome do arquivo formatado:

```
string formatarItem(string item) {
    return System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(item).Replace("_", " ");
}
```

Então, para adicionar na lista, chame a função assim:

```
ListBox1.Items.Add(formatarItem(arquivo));
```

Answer (score 4):

Para que o nome dos arquivos selecionados sejam listados no controle `list`, implementei o código abaixo.

Observe que o [`MultiSelect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.multiselect%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) permite o retorno de uma coleção que pode ser obtida pelo [`FileNames`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filenames%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) e inserida imediatamente pelo [`Items.AddRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.items%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) do `list`.

```
ofd1.Title = "Selecione os arquivos";
ofd1.MultiSelect = true;
ofd1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";

DialogResult dr = ofd1.ShowDialog();

// Se OK - Insere todos os arquivos selecionados pelo usuário no listbox
if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)   
    listArquivos.Items.AddRange(ofd1.FileNames);
```